# Is there a way to query a MySQL DB twice and add the results from the second query to the same array as the results from the first query?

Tags: php, mysql

I am searching the DB for users by name here.  I have preg_split() looking for the space between first and last name to split them up and searching for the names separately, but I want to set it up so that if the user just puts in either first or last, it will search both the 'first_name' and 'last_name' fields for the single name put in.
Ex.  'Shannon Phillips' will search first_name for Shannon and last_name for Phillips, but if I just put Phillips, I want it to search both first_name and last_name for Phillips. I'm assuming I would just query the DB twice, and somehow append the results from the second query to the end of the first.

```
function nameProcess(){
    if($_SESSION['search_engine_option'] == 'name'){
        $name = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $_SESSION['search_engine_input']);
        if(empty($name['0'])){
            $first  = db_query('SELECT * FROM {tls_active_applicants} WHERE `first_name` = `'.$name['1'].'`');
            $last   = db_query('SELECT * FROM {tls_active_applicants} WHERE `last_name` = `'.$name['1'].'`');
        }elseif(empty($name['1'])){
            $first  = db_query('SELECT * FROM {tls_active_applicants} WHERE `first_name` = `'.$name['0'].'`');
            $last   = db_query('SELECT * FROM {tls_active_applicants} WHERE `last_name` = `'.$name['0'].'`');
        }   

}
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Comment: Ow.  You sir, have problems far beyond the functional aspects of creating arrays.  Your code appears to be very susceptible to sql injection, and any application using this code would be insecure and likely to get your database compromised.  Beyond that, you should probably be trying to separate the retrieval of data from the use of that data, via a separate method or function to get the original data, and then manipulate it afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Why not to use OR ?

```
    if(empty($name['0'])){
        $first  = db_query('SELECT * FROM {tls_active_applicants} WHERE `first_name` = `'.$name['1'].'` OR `last_name` = `'.$name['1'].'`');
    }elseif(empty($name['1'])){
        $first  = db_query('SELECT * FROM {tls_active_applicants} WHERE `first_name` = `'.$name['0'].'` OR `last_name` = `'.$name['0'].'`');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can, using [union](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-union-mysql.aspx), but in this case you might as wel merge the 2 queries into one, by using 'OR':

```
SELECT * FROM {tls_active_applicants} 
    WHERE `first_name` = `'.$name['0'].'` 
    OR `last_name` = `'.$name['0'].'`
```